Finitely sampling the n-dimensional unit sphere, such that the angular distance is bounded
Consider the unit, $d$-dimensional sphere $U^d = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \|\mathbf{x}\| = 1\}$. I am looking for a finite family of vectors $\mathcal{F} \subset U^d$, such that,
$$
\forall \mathbf{x} \in U^d~~ \exists \mathbf{v}\in \mathcal{F} \text{ with } \measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{v}) \leq \psi \quad (1),
$$
for some $\psi \in (0, \pi)$. Using cosines, we can rewrite $(1)$ as,
$$
\forall \mathbf{x} \in U^d~~ \exists \mathbf{v}\in \mathcal{F} \text{ with } \cos(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{v}) \geq \varepsilon \quad (2),
$$
with $\varepsilon = \arccos(\psi)$ and $\delta \in (-1, 1)$.
I think a intuitive (and possible naive) solution would be to sample the unit sphere $U^d$, with respect to the hyperspherical coordinates as described in another question of mine. In greater detail let $B^d(\theta) \subset U^d$ be the family of vectors,
$$
B^d(\theta) = \left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d \left\vert \mathbf{x} = (1, k_1\theta, \dots, k_{d-1}\theta), ~~k_i \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right], i \in [d-1] \right.\right\}.
$$
Intuitively, using the triangular inequality for angles $B^d\left(\frac{\psi}{d-1}\right)$ could work (see discussion in the previous post). On the other hand, the number of vectors in $B^d(\theta)$ grows exponentially, w.r.t. the dimention $d$. Is there a better way to do this? Can I avoid the exponential growth of the desired family $\mathcal{F}$? I found some resemblance of the above problem with the kissing number problem, but I could not derive a proper reduction. Are the two problems equivalent?
Thank you in advance for any help. Any suggestion to related literature will also be appreciated.

Do you want an explicit formula or a proof they exist? The number of vectors necessary will definitely grow exponentially with the dimension though

Preferably I would like an explicit formula, in order to construct an algorithm. Yeah, I understand that the size of the family will grow exponentially, due to the curse of directionality. On the other hand, I had a hard time even constructing such a set and prove the desired property.

I have an idea using the fact that $|x-y| = 2(1-\cos(x,y))$ and the construction of 2 possible $d$-dimensional sphere of a certain radius with $d$ points. I can ensure that the algorithm ends but I have no clear bound since it is already impossible to have regular polyhedrons with an arbitrary number of faces, however in practice it should not use that many more step than the minimal way to obtain them. However the computations must be very hard

Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I cannot understand fully the solution you are suggesting. I wasn't even familiar with the identity you are mentioning. Could you elaborate more, writing down your method as a full answer?

I must think this trough a bit before but I was ensuring this kind of answer would be a satisfying one for you

From your point of view, do you think that the family $B^d(\theta)$ as defined above will do the work? Or am I completely off?

What does the notation $[\frac{\pi}{\theta}]$ mean?

We have $[n] = {1, 2, \dots, n}$, so roughly $\left[ \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right] = \left{1, 2, \dots, \left\lceil \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right\rceil \right}$.

Ok I see. My idea was to use a triangulation using d-simplexes like it is done in certain algebraic topology proofs. I get your idea, but how do you ensure that theta is sufficiently small? It seems complicated to compute

If I am not mistaken to achieve upper bound $\psi$, we need to set $\theta = \frac{\psi}{d-1}$ using the triangular inequality for angles.

I'm not really familiar with angle triangular inequalities .

I found a way to sample the sphere in $\left(\frac{2\pi}{\varphi}\right)^d$ points at most with no arcsin computations and a very well distributed cloud of points using hypercubes. I'll edit my answer when I can

My other answer was false and cut the $d$ sphere into "normalised $d$-simplexes" of volume as small as we want I figured it out by coding the algorithm which I wrote down in python with a small trick to avoid using recursion since it does not suit this programming language.
Indeed you can have a very small
volume and a very large diameter...
This answer will give more appropriate results using hypercubes to cut the sphere.
Lower bound for the number of needed points.
First let us make an observation: If we defined the "angular disks" as the surface defined by points on the sphere that have an angle with $x$ smaller that $\theta$ or
$$C^{d-1} (x,\theta) = \{y \in \mathbb S^d \mid \langle x,y \rangle \ge \cos \theta \}$$
Then the collection $(\mathbb D ^{d-1}(x_k,\varphi))_{k\le N}$ must cover the $d$-sphere, which means we have
$$N \ge \dfrac{\operatorname{Vol} \mathbb S^d}{\operatorname{Vol}  C^{d-1} (\varphi)}$$

I omitted the $x$ for simplicity since the volume does not depend on it.

Now we observe that
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Vol} C^{d-1} (\varphi) 
&= \int_{\theta=0}^\varphi \int\limits_{x \in  \mathbb{S}^{d-1}(\sin \theta)} 1 \operatorname d \! x  \operatorname d \! \theta\\
&= \int_{\theta=0}^\varphi \int\limits_{y \in  \mathbb{S}^{d-1}} \sin(\theta)^{d-1} \operatorname d \! y  \operatorname d \! \theta\\
&= \operatorname{Vol} \mathbb S^{d-1} \cdot \int_{0}^\varphi  \sin(\theta)^{d-1} \operatorname d \! \theta
\end{align*}$$
Now I only know the result for $\varphi \in \{0,\frac{\pi}{2}\}$, so we we only observe that
$$\int_{0}^\varphi  \sin(\theta)^{d-1} \operatorname d \! \theta \le \int_{0}^\varphi  \theta^{d-1} \operatorname d \! \theta = \dfrac{\varphi^d}{d}$$
Now if we recall that $\operatorname{Vol} \mathbb{S}^{d-1} = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$, we get
$$N \ge \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\int_{0}^\varphi  \sin(\theta)^{d-1} \operatorname d \! \theta} \frac{\Gamma((d+1)/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)} \ge \frac{d \sqrt{\pi}}{\varphi^d} \frac{\Gamma((d+1)/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)} \sim \frac{d^{3/2}}{\varphi^d} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Cutting into hypercubes.
The strategy is almost the same as the one for the simplex but with a few modifications.
Motivation
Since we cannot rely on the volume, we need to have control on the edges, thus we would like for example to divide the edges by two at every step. We have one problem with the simplex:

When $d\in \{1,2\}$, we can cut the regular $d$-simplex in respectfully $2$ and $4$ smaller simplexes which edges length are halved.
There is no way to do this for $d \ge 3$.

Our solution is to use the $d$-cube instead of the $d$-simplex: its vertices can be labeled with $\mathbb{F}_2^d$ and we can cut the hypercube into $2^d$ hypercubes of halved length just by considering for each vertex $v$ the hypercube which vertices are $\left\{ \frac{v + v'}{2}, \, v' \in V \right\}$.
Algorithm:
I will denote $n(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ the normalised vector of $x$.
Algorithm 1

Compute a $d+1$-dimensional cube inscribed in the $d$-sphere.

For each of its faces, apply the second algorithm.


Algorithm 2
You have the data of a $d$-dimensional (convex) pave with vertices $V$ inscribed in the sphere.

If it is small enough return its barycentrum.
If not, return all the points given by this algorithm applied to $\left\{ n \left( \frac{v + v'}{2} \right), \, v' \in V \right\}$.

Termination of the algorithm
Let us set $\alpha = \|v - v' \|$ for $\|v \| = 1 = \|v'\| $, we have

$2\langle v,v' \rangle = 2- \alpha^2$.
$\|v + v'\|^2 = 4 - \alpha^2$.
With this, if $u = n\left(\frac{v+v'}{2} \right) $, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\|v-u\|^2 &=\|v\|^2 - \|u\|^2 + 2 \langle v,u \rangle\\
&= 2 - 2\left\langle v,\frac{v+v'}{\|v+v'\|} \right\rangle\\
&= 2 - \frac{2}{\|v+v'\|}\left( \langle v, v \rangle + \langle v,v' \rangle \right)\\
&= 2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-\alpha^2}}\left( 1 + 1 + \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \right)\\
&= 2 - \sqrt{4-\alpha^2}.
\end{align*}$$

This means that
$$\frac{\|v-u\|^2}{\|v-v'\|^2} = \frac{2 - \sqrt{4-\alpha^2}}{\alpha^2} = \frac{1}{2 + \sqrt{4-\alpha^2}}$$
This means that if we set $f(x) = \frac{x}{2 + \sqrt{4-x}} = 2-\sqrt{4-x}$, $d_0 = 4\frac{d}{d+1}$ and $d_{k+1} = f(d_k)$, the square of any length between to vertices is smaller than $d_k$ after $k$ steps. It is clear that $d_k$ converges to $0$ with geometric speed, and we can prove that we have both $d_k \sim d_0 \cdot C \cdot 4^{-k}$ and $d_k \le d_0 \cdot C \cdot 4^{-k}$ by looking in detail at the infinite product given by the last inequality of Asymptotic equivalent of sequence defined by a recursion relation..
Furthermore, we can bind $C$ with $C < 2\cdot\frac{8^2}{7^2}$.
Now since we want any point in the convex hull of $V_k$ to be at angular distance of some point in $V_k$, we just need to have $\operatorname{diam} V_k \le \varphi$, which means if we chose (it is prettier in my opinion) the normalised barycentrum of $V_k$ such that $\sqrt{d_k} \le \varphi$, it is sufficient (but maybe not optimal we can't be sure and it is probably not).
We thus set $ c = \sqrt{4C} < \frac{16 \sqrt{2}}{7}<3.233$ and we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{d_k} & \le & \varphi\\
&\Leftarrow\\
c\cdot 2^{-k} & \le & \varphi\\
&\Leftarrow\\
k & \ge & \log_2 \left(\frac{c}{\varphi}\right) \\
&\Leftarrow\\
k & = & \left\lceil \log_2 \left(\frac{c}{\varphi}\right) \right\rceil \le 1 + \log_2 \left(\frac{c}{\varphi}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$
But we need to count the number of points. For each face, at the step $k$ we have $2^{kd}$ faces to deal with and we begin with $2(d+1)$ faces thus we have
$$ N \le 2(d+1)2^{kd} \le 2(d+1) \cdot 2^{d\left(1 + \log_2 \left(\frac{c}{\varphi}\right)\right)} = (d+1) \cdot\frac{2^{d+1}c^d}{\varphi^d} = \mathcal o \left(\frac{6.465}{\varphi} \right)^d$$
which is not as good as the (impossible) bound $\frac{d^{3/2}}{\varphi^d} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ but still very good and not hyperexponential.

Numerical estimations give me $c = 3.142451272494134$ for $d_0 = 4$ (so it is uniform) (not so far from my formal estimation), this gives us $N = o(6.285/\varphi)^d$. We also note that this is (not surprisingly) very close to $2\pi$.

Remark
A further analysis tells us that for a cut with $d$-dimensional pave, we have
$$N \ge \frac{2^{1-d} \sqrt{\pi} (\pi d)^{d/2}}{\arcsin(\varphi)^{d} \Gamma\left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)} \sim \frac{ \left( \frac{ \pi e }{2 } \right)^{\frac{d+1}{2}} }{ \sqrt{\pi} \arcsin(\varphi)^d } = \mathcal o \left(\frac{2.1}{ \varphi} \right)^d$$
so our bound is still very good.
Code
I coded the different programs with a small trick to avoid using recursion in python, feel free to check it out.
I plotted the results in dimension $2$, in blue you have the "faces" and in green the normalised barycentrums.
Code for the hypercube cut
## Imports

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


## Constantes

D=2
Phi= np.pi/6

## Fonctions

def faces_hypercube(d):
    """renvoie une liste des faces de dimension d d'un hypercube de dimension d+1 et de demi-diagonale 1"""
    
    c= 1/np.sqrt(d+1)
    
    liste_indices_faces = [[] for i in range(2*(d+1))]
    points = np.zeros((2**(d+1),d+1))
    faces = np.zeros((2*(d+1),2**d,d+1))
    
    for k in range (2**(d+1)):
        j = k
        for i in range(d+1):
            l=j%2
            points[k,i] = 2*l - 1
            liste_indices_faces[2*i+l].append(k)
            j = j//2
    
    points = c*points
    for i in range (2*(d+1)):
        for j in range (2**d):
            faces[i,j] = points[liste_indices_faces[i][j]]
    return faces
    

f = lambda x : 2 - np.sqrt(4-x)

def processus (d : int, face_init : np.ndarray, diag_init : float, diag_ref : float):
    
    """Prend en entrée:
    - d: une dimension.
    - face_init: une "face" d'un hyperpavé de dimension d+1 avec la géométrie d-sphérique.
    - diag_init: le carré de sa diagonale la plus longue.
    - diag_ref: le carré d'une longueur de diagonale de référence
    
    Renvoie un couple (liste_faces, liste_points) sur la sphère étant les normalisations des barycentres de d-simplexes dont:
    - les sommets sont sur la d-sphère.
    - les normalisations triangulent la d-sphère.
    - l'aire de chaque simplexe formé en remplaçant un sommet par le point associé est plus petite que l'aire de référence."""
    
    
    # c = 2*(1+np.sqrt(1/(d+1)))
    liste_face_a_traiter = [face_init]
    liste_diag_a_traiter = [diag_init]
    liste_points = []
    liste_faces = []
    while liste_face_a_traiter != []: # Vérifie si toutes les conditions sont remplies
        
        face = liste_face_a_traiter.pop()
        diag = liste_diag_a_traiter.pop()
        
        if diag <= diag_ref:
        
            y = np.sum(face,axis = 0)
            x= y/np.linalg.norm(y)
            liste_points.append(x)
            liste_faces.append(face)
        
        else:
            
            nouv_faces = np.array([[(face[i]+face[j])/np.linalg.norm(face[i]+face[j]) for j in range(2**d)] for i in range(2**d)])
            
            for k in range(2**d):
                liste_face_a_traiter.append(nouv_faces[k])
                liste_diag_a_traiter.append( #diag/c)
                f(diag))
    
    return (liste_faces,liste_points)


def quadrillage(d, phi):
    # Génération des sommets du simplexe régulier dans la sphère d-dimensionnelle de rayon 1
    liste_faces_init = faces_hypercube(d)
    diag_init = 4*d/(d+1)
    
    # Résultats de process appliqué aux listes privées de chaque s_k pour 0 <= k <= d+1
    liste_faces_tot = []
    points_tot = []
    for face in liste_faces_init:
        (liste_faces,points) = processus(d,face,diag_init,phi**2)
        
        liste_faces_tot.extend(liste_faces)
        points_tot.extend(points)  # Concatenation des résultats
    return (liste_faces_tot, points_tot)


def traitement (face3d):
    
    segments = [point for point in face3d]
    (segments[2],segments[3]) = (segments[3],segments[2])
    segments.append(segments[0])
    return segments
  
def interpolate_geodesic(p1, p2, num_points=50):
    """
    Interpole des points le long de l'arc géodésique entre deux points sur la sphère unité.
    """
    # Normaliser les points (au cas où ils ne sont pas exactement sur la sphère)
    p1 = p1 / np.linalg.norm(p1)
    p2 = p2 / np.linalg.norm(p2)
    
    # Calcul de l'angle entre les deux points
    theta = np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(p1, p2), -1.0, 1.0))
    
    # Générer des interpolations
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    interpolated_points = np.array([
        (np.sin((1 - ti) * theta) * p1 + np.sin(ti * theta) * p2) / np.sin(theta)
        for ti in t
    ])
    
    return interpolated_points

## Exécution


# Liste de points en 3D
# points = 
(liste_faces,points) = quadrillage(D,Phi)
# print(len(points))
# 
# 
# Création de la figure pour le graphique 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Extraire les coordonnées x, y, z des points
x_vals = [point[0] for point in points]
y_vals = [point[1] for point in points]
z_vals = [point[2] for point in points]

#Affichage des points dans l'espace 3D
ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='lime', marker='o')


for face in liste_faces:
    # Tracer les arcs géodésiques entre les points du polygone
    segment = traitement(face)
    for i in range(len(face)):
        p1 = segment[i]
        p2 = segment[(i + 1)]  # Prochain point (ferme le polygone)
        
        # Générer les points de l'arc géodésique
        arc_points = interpolate_geodesic(p1, p2)
        
        # Extraire les coordonnées x, y, z des points
        x_vals = arc_points[:, 0]
        y_vals = arc_points[:, 1]
        z_vals = arc_points[:, 2]
        
        # Tracer l'arc géodésique
        ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='b')
    
    # Afficher les points
    x_vals = [point[0] for point in face]
    y_vals = [point[1] for point in face]
    z_vals = [point[2] for point in face]
    ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='r', marker='o')

#Ajouter des labels aux axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

#Afficher le graphique
plt.show()

Code for the original simplex cut
This ones ensures that the cut has simplexes of volumes $\le$ Aire_min
## Imports

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


## Constantes

D=2
Aire_min = 1.5

## Fonctions

def simplexe_regulier(d,d_init):
    """Crée un simplexe régulier inscrit dans la sphère unité de dimension d"""
    
    if d == 1:
        return np.array([[1]+[0]*(d_init-1), [-1]+[0]*(d_init-1)])
    else:
        c = np.sqrt((d**2 - 1)/d**2) 
        sommet = np.array([0] * (d-1) + [1] + [0]*(d_init-d))
        decalage = -sommet / (d)
        
        # Ajouter le sommet au final
        return np.append(c * simplexe_regulier(d - 1,d_init) + decalage, [sommet], axis=0)


def processus (d : int, simplexe : np.ndarray, aire_init : float, aire_ref : float):
    
    """Prend en entrée:
    - d: une dimension.
    - simplexe: un d-simplexe dont les sommets sont imbriqués dans la d-sphère.
    - aire_init: son aire.
    - aire_ref: une aire de référence
    
    Renvoie une liste de d-simplexes découpant la portion de la d-sphère contenue dans la normalisation du d-simplexe d'origine dont les aires sont plus petites que l'aire de référence."""
    
    if np.shape(simplexe) != (d+1, d+1):
            raise TypeError("Les dimensions du simplexes sont erronnées")
    
    liste_aires = [aire_init]
    liste_simplexe_a_traiter = [simplexe]
    liste_simplexes_finaux = []
    
    while liste_simplexe_a_traiter != []: # Vérifie si toutes les conditions sont remplies
        
        simp = liste_simplexe_a_traiter.pop()
        aire = liste_aires.pop()
        if aire <= aire_ref:
            
            liste_simplexes_finaux.append(simp)
        
        else:
            
            y = np.sum(simp,axis = 0)
            coeff = np.linalg.norm(y)
            x = y/coeff
            aire_nouvelle = aire/coeff
            
            for k in range(d+1):
                
                new_simp = np.copy(simp)
                new_simp[k] = x
                # ajoute le simplexe contenant les mêmes points que simp sauf le point s qui a été remplacé par x
                liste_simplexe_a_traiter.append(new_simp)
                liste_aires.append(aire_nouvelle)
    
    return liste_simplexes_finaux


def quadrillage(d, aire_min):
    # Génération des sommets du simplexe régulier dans la sphère d-dimensionnelle de rayon 1
    simplexe_init = simplexe_regulier(d+1,d+1)
    aire_face = np.sqrt((d+2)**d / (d+1)**(d-1))
    # Résultats de process appliqué aux listes privées de chaque s_k pour 0 <= k <= d+1
    results = []
    for k in range(d + 2):
        
        face = [simplexe_init[i] for i in range(d + 2) if i != k]  # Retirer s_k
        results.extend(processus(d,face,aire_face,aire_min))  # Concatenation des résultats
    return results


## Exécution


def interpolate_geodesic(p1, p2, num_points=50):
    """
    Interpole des points le long de l'arc géodésique entre deux points sur la sphère unité.
    """
    # Normaliser les points (au cas où ils ne sont pas exactement sur la sphère)
    p1 = p1 / np.linalg.norm(p1)
    p2 = p2 / np.linalg.norm(p2)
    
    # Calcul de l'angle entre les deux points
    theta = np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(p1, p2), -1.0, 1.0))
    
    # Générer des interpolations
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    interpolated_points = np.array([
        (np.sin((1 - ti) * theta) * p1 + np.sin(ti * theta) * p2) / np.sin(theta)
        for ti in t
    ])
    
    return interpolated_points

# Exemple de liste de polygones (chaque polygone est une liste de points 3D sur la sphère unité)
liste_simplexes = quadrillage(D, Aire_min)

# Création de la figure pour le graphique 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for simplexe in liste_simplexes:
    # Tracer les arcs géodésiques entre les points du polygone
    for i in range(len(simplexe)):
        p1 = simplexe[i]
        p2 = simplexe[(i + 1) % len(simplexe)]  # Prochain point (ferme le polygone)
        
        # Générer les points de l'arc géodésique
        arc_points = interpolate_geodesic(p1, p2)
        
        # Extraire les coordonnées x, y, z des points
        x_vals = arc_points[:, 0]
        y_vals = arc_points[:, 1]
        z_vals = arc_points[:, 2]
        
        # Tracer l'arc géodésique
        ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='b')
    
    # Afficher les points
    x_vals = [point[0] for point in simplexe]
    y_vals = [point[1] for point in simplexe]
    z_vals = [point[2] for point in simplexe]
    ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, c='r', marker='o')

# Ajouter des labels aux axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Afficher le graphique
plt.show()

```


Disclaimer
This cut of the hypersphere answers to a similar problem but not the original problem. I leave it here for the time being because I believe it is still interesting but this is not a valid answer.
What does it do? It cuts the sphere into simplexes of volume as small as we want.
Intro
First let us make a quick observation: if $x, \, y \in \mathbb S^d$,
$$\|x-y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 - 2 \langle x,y\rangle = 2(1-\cos(x,y))$$
This means $\cos(x,y) \geq \epsilon \iff \|x-y\|^2 \leq 2(1-\epsilon)$. You can also notice that since $\cos(t) \geq 1-\frac{t^2}{2}$, it suffices to have $\|x-y\|^2 \leq \varphi^2$ which is an easier condition to check.
What I mean here is that if we can "triangulate" the surface of the sphere into a finite number of compact $d$-dimensional varieties $V$ containing some points $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ verifying
$$\max_{x \in V} \max_{k} \|x-v_k\| \leq \varphi$$
then we have won.
So my idea is the following: consider the regular $d+1$-simplex $\Delta_{d+1} = \operatorname{Conv}\{x_0,\dots,x_{d+1}\} \subset \mathbb R^{d+1}$ with $\forall 0\le k \le d, \, \|x_k\| = 1$. For each $k$ you have a $d$-simplex
$$\Delta_d^k = \operatorname{Conv} \{x_j, \, j \neq k\} \subset \partial \Delta_{d+1}$$
Result on the simplexes
Let us get some results about the regular simplex. Suppose it is of dimension $d$, with length of the edges $e$, we want to know the radius $R(d,e)$ of the $d$-dimensional sphere its vertices belong to. For that we have $\|x_k\| = R(d,e)$, $\|x_i-x_j\|^2 = a^2 \delta_i^j$, $\sum_{k=0}^d x_k= 0$, we thus have
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= \left\| \sum_{k=0}^d x_k \right \|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^d \|x_k\|^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} \langle x_i, x_j \rangle\\
&= (d+1)R(d,e)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j} (\|x_i\|^2 + \|x_j\|^2 -\| x_i - x_j\|^2)\\
&= (d+1)R(d,e)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j} (2R(d,e)^2 -e^2)\\
&= (d+1)^2 R(d,e)^2 -\frac{d(d+1)}{2}e^2\\
&= (d+1) \left( (d+1)R(d,e)^2 - \frac{d}{2}e^2  \right)
\end{align*}$$
which gives us
$$R(d,e)^2 = \frac{d}{2(d+1)} e^2$$
Now we can also set $y_n = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{k \neq n} x_k = -\frac{x_n}{d}$ the barycentre of $\Delta_{d-1}^n$, we then have for $j \neq n$
$$\begin{align*}
\langle x_n,dx_j- x_n \rangle &= d\langle x_n,x_j\rangle - \|x_n\|^2\\
&= \frac{d}{2} \left(2 R(d,e)^2-e^2 \right) - R(d,e)^2\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$
which means $(\mathbb R \cdot y_n) \bot \Delta_{d-1}^n$, thus
$$\operatorname{dist} (0,\Delta_{d-1}^n) = \|y_n\| = \frac{R(d,e)}{d}$$
and since all these constitute the faces of $\Delta_d$, we have:
$$r(d,e) = \operatorname{dist} (0,\partial \Delta_{d}) =  \frac{R(d,e)}{d}$$
here $r(d,e)$ is the radius of the inscribed sphere.
Lastly, the height of $\Delta_n$ is given thanks to the orthogonality by:
$$h(d,e) = \|x_0-y_0\| = \left(1+\frac{1}{d} \right) \|x_0\| = \frac{d+1}{d} R(d,e) = \sqrt{\frac{d+1}{2d}} e.$$
This directly gives us the volume $V(d,e)$ of $\Delta_d$ since we have the recursion formula:
$$V(d,e) = \frac{h(d,e)}{d} \cdot V(d-1,e) = \frac{\sqrt{d+1}}{\sqrt{2d} d} eV(d-1,e)$$
thus $V(d,e) = \sqrt{\frac{d+1}{2^d}}\frac{e^d}{d!}$.
Algorithm
Now what will our algorithm be?
It will be a recursive algorithm, basically, the recursive algorithm takes a (non necessarily regular) $d$-simplex which vertices $\{x_0,\dots,x_d\}$ are embedded in the $d$-dimensional sphere and defines $y = \frac{1}{d+1} \sum_{k=0}^d x_d$ the barycentrum and $\tilde y = \frac{y}{\|y\|}$

If $\max_{k} \|y-x_k\|^2 \leq \varphi^2$, then we stop and return $\{x_0,\dots,x_d,y\}$.
If $\max_{k} \|y-x_k\|^2 > \varphi^2$, then apply the procedure on the simplexes given by the sets of points $\left( \{y\} \bigcup \{x_j,\, j \neq k \}, \, 0 \le k \le d \right)$.

And how do we initialise it? we take $\Delta_{d+1}$ and we take the union of the sets return by the procedure applied to $\Delta_d^k$ for $0\le k \le d$.
The condition is sufficient since for $z \in \operatorname{Conv} \left(\{y\} \bigcup \{x_j,\, j \neq k \} \right)$, $\|z-y\| \leq \max_{k} \|y-x_k\|^2$. Now if we take
Proof of finiteness and complexity
What is the max depth of this algorithm?
Since the volume is maximal when the simplex is regular, we need to ensure that the volume of the "terminal" simplex $V$ is smaller than $V(d,\varphi)$ since in this case we will have at least one point for which every edge having it as a vertex will be of width at most $\varphi$ which is enough for us to ensure the property we need.
Now suppose we apply the procedure to $\{x_0,\dots,x_d\}$, we consider $c$ the centre of the circumscribed $d-1$-sphere. We know that $\min_k \|y-x_k\| \leq \|c-x_k\| = R$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed $d-1$-sphere. With a simple pythagore applied to $y$ and the minimal $x_k$, we get $\|y\|^2 \le 1-R^2$.
Now consider the simplexes $D_k$ given by $(y,x_j,j \neq k)$ and the simplexes $\tilde D_k$ given by $(\tilde y,x_j,j \neq k)$, since $(y,x_j,j \notin \{k,i\})$ where $i \neq k$ forms a base, we define the linear application $f_k$ by:
$$f_k (x_j) = x_j , \qquad f_k(y) = \tilde y$$
We have $f_k(D_k) = \tilde{D_k}$ and $\det f_k = \frac{1}{\|y\|} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-R^2}}$, which means
$$\operatorname{Vol}  D_k \le \operatorname{Vol} \tilde D_k \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-R^2}}\operatorname{Vol}  D_k$$
So we only need to determine $\operatorname{Vol}  D_k$. It is fairly simple knowing $D$ our base simplex, since up to an affine transformation, $D$ is regular. Since affine transformation preserve barycentres, if we show that all the $D_k$ are of the same volume when $D$ is regular, we win.
Of course this is the case, it suffices to make $\operatorname{Isom}(D)$ the group of isometries preserving $D$ act on $D$. Since it is generated by the reflexions given by the affine hyperplanes generated by $(\frac{x_j + x_k}{2},x_i, i \neq j,k) $ (which are corresponding to the transpositions $\tau_{j,k}$) we conclude that the volume does not depend on $k$ which means
$$\operatorname{Vol} D_k = \frac{1}{d+1} \operatorname{Vol} D$$
so
$$\frac{1}{d+1}\operatorname{Vol}  D \le \operatorname{Vol} \tilde D_k \leq \frac{1}{(d+1)\sqrt{1-R^2}}\operatorname{Vol}  D$$
The worst case is at the first step, so we necessarily have $R$ smaller than the radius of the $d$-dimensional regular simplex of edge width $e$ verifying $R(d+1,e) = 1$  so $e^2 = \frac{2(d+2)}{d+1}$ (basically the radius of the sphere inscribing the first simplexes we deal with).
But during the first step it is not enough, so we will compute directly the $\|y'\|$ obtained at the second step. Basically the first $y$ is $-x_{0}/(d+1)$ for example (it does not matter). Which means $\tilde y = -x_{0}$, we thus have $y' = \frac{1}{d+1} \left(-x_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^d x_k \right) = - \frac{2x_0 + x_{d+1}}{d+1}$ for example (excluding $x_{d+1}$). This gives us
$$\begin{align*}
(d+1)^2 \|y'\|^2 
&= 4 \|x_0\|^2 + \|x_{d+1}\| - 2 \langle x_0,x_{d+1}\rangle \\
&= 5 - 2 (1-e^2/2) \\
&= 3-e^2\\
&= \frac{d+1}{d-1}
\end{align*}$$
Which means after step two we always have
$$\frac{1}{d+1}\operatorname{Vol}  D \le \operatorname{Vol} \tilde D_k \leq \sqrt{\frac{d-1}{d+1}}\operatorname{Vol}  D$$
We can probably obtain a much better bound by working a bit more, but I think it is sufficient for now (don't hesitate to check the bottom). We now know that at depth $k$ of the algorithm, we have
$$\operatorname{Vol} D \leq \left(\frac{d-1}{d+1}\right)^{(k-1)/2} \operatorname{Col} (\Delta_d^0) = \left(\frac{d-1}{d+1}\right)^{(k-1)/2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{d+1}{2^d}}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2(d+1)}{d}}^d}{d!} = \left(\frac{d-1}{d+1}\right)^{(k-1)/2} \cdot \frac{(d+1)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}{d!}$$
And we only need to guarantee that $\operatorname{Vol} D \leq V(d,\varphi)$ so it suffices to have
$$\left(\frac{d-1}{d+1}\right)^{(k-1)/2}\cdot \frac{(d+1)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}{d!} \le \sqrt{\frac{d+1}{2^d}} \frac{\varphi^d}{d!}$$
which means
$$\left(\frac{d-1}{d+1}\right)^{(k-1)/2} \le  \left(\frac{\varphi}{\sqrt{2(d+1)}} \right)^d$$
or more conveniently
$$\left(\frac{d+1}{d-1}\right)^{(k-1)/2} \ge  \left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d$$
But since we want an estimation we will use the inequality
$$\frac{d+1}{d-1} = \frac{1+1/d}{1-1/d} \geq (1+1/d)^2 \geq 1+2/d$$
and $(1+\epsilon)^{j} \ge 1 + j \epsilon$ so it suffices to have
$$\frac{(k-1)}{d} \ge \left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d$$
or
$$d \ge 1+ d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d$$
So a depth of $$k = 1 + \left\lceil d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d\right\rceil$$
suffices.
Now how many points at most does it makes? If you apply the procedure, you create one point and apply the procedure to $d+1$ new smaller simplexes, so if you have depth $k$, you will create at most
$$N=d+2 + (d+2)(1 + (d+1) + (d+1)^2 + \cdots + (d+1)^{k-1}) = d+2 + (d+2) \frac{(d+1)^k -1}{d} \\
= (d+2) \frac{d-1+ (d+1)^k}{d}$$
points.
But we have $k \leq 2 + d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d $, so this gives
$$\begin{align*}
N & \le \frac{d+2}{d} \left(d-1+ (d+1)^{2+d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d} \right)\\
&\sim  (d+1)^{2+d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d} 
\end{align*}$$
Final comments
Now The varieties I was talking about at the beginning are given by the simplexes we obtain through the algorithm, i.e. for $D$ defined by $ \{x_0,\dots x_d\}$ such that $\max_{k\geq 1} \|x_0-x_k\| \le \varphi$, we define
$$V = (\mathbb{R}_+ \cdot D) \cap \mathbb S^d$$
Now if we take $v \in V$, we know that $\partial \left(\operatorname{span}(v,x_0) \cap V \right) = \{x_0,v'\}$ with $v' \in V'=\left(\mathbb R_+ \cdot \operatorname{Conv}(x_1,\dots,x_d) \right) \cap \mathbb S^d$, but
$$V'=\left(\mathbb R_+ \cdot \operatorname{Conv}(x_1,\dots,x_d) \right) \cap \left( \mathbb S^d \cap \operatorname{Span}(x_2-x_1,\dots,x_d-x_1) \right)$$
which is the intersection of a $d-1$-dimensional sphere with a cone generated by a $d-1$-simplex which vertices are embedded in it, so if we show that $\|v-x_0\|\le \|v'-x_0\| $, we have by recursion on the dimension $\|v-x_0\|\le \max_{k\geq 1} \|x_0-x_k\|$.
For this, we have a parametrisation of $\operatorname{span}(v,x_0) \cap V $ given by
$$\left\{\phi(t)=\frac{(1-t)v' + tx_0}{\|(1-t)v' + tx_0\|}, t \in [0,1] \right\} $$
So it goes back to the dimension one case, a small drawing allows us to get the result.
This means we have for all $v \in V$, $\|v-x_0\| \leq \varphi$.
Observation:
If we are a bit clever, this means we only need to keep the final points, not the initial, so here is a new algorithm (more efficient in the number of points):

If $\max_{k} \|y-x_k\|^2 \leq \varphi^2$, then we stop and return $\{y\}$.
If $\max_{k} \|y-x_k\|^2 > \varphi^2$, then apply the procedure on the simplexes given by the sets of points $\left( \{y\} \bigcup \{x_j,\, j \neq k \}, \, 0 \le k \le d \right)$.

This means that we only need the endpoints, so if we have a depth of $k$, we get at most $(d+2)(d+1)^{k-1}$ points which means
$$N \leq (d+1)^{1+d\left(\frac{\sqrt{2(d+1)}}{\varphi} \right)^d} .$$
Last remark
The effective complexity is probably way less since we must have very quickly $R<<1$ thus after a few step
$$\frac{1}{d+1}\operatorname{Vol}  D \le \operatorname{Vol} \tilde D_k \leq \frac{1 + \epsilon}{(d+1)}\operatorname{Vol}  D$$
Especially after $j_0(d)$ steps we would have
$$\frac{1}{d+1}\operatorname{Vol}  D \le \operatorname{Vol} \tilde D_k \leq \frac{1 }{d}\operatorname{Vol}  D$$
which gives in the end a nicer looking bond for $k$:
$$k \ge j_0(d) + \frac{d}{2} + d \log_d\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\varphi}  \right)$$
this gives
$$N \le (d+2)(d+1)^{j_0(d) + \frac{d}{2}}  \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\varphi}  \right)^{d}$$

Note that the first one almost implies the second but in reality, I used a better approximation of $k$ to get the bound on $N$.
I also believe that $j_0(d) = O(d)$ at least if not $o(d)$.


Thank you vary much for your answer and the detailed analysis! This is quite different than what I was expecting, but it is often useful to get proven wrong! Your answer is quite intuitive if you think about it, it reminds me of Bushenkov's algorithm for approximating convex bodies by polytopes.

@MerkourisPapamichail This cut is actually not fitted for your problem, you should remove the "accepted answer" and check my other answer, which has a solid proof and works very well, I verified it for dimensions $\le$ 5 and small $\varphi$ with my computer. This answer is still interesting if you want to cut it into small volumes simplexes.
